# Hard coded name of field not displaying value

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I am trying to extract a value from a specific attribute coming from an XML file with the following structure
[image]

My problems is that it returns to me a null value like the following

[image]

The XPath expression I use to extract the value is the following which is a valid
as Jasper doesn't throw any exceptions with the expression.
[image]

Can someone please point me in the right direction as I ran away from BIRT due to the same issue. Any shed of light is highly appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about Jasper but is selecting the `FLD` element what you want? Shouldn't you select the text node inside it, i.e. using `FLD[@NAME='Phone']/text()` or `string(FLD[@NAME='Phone'])`?

Comment: Thanks Paul for the quick reply, yes I want to get the value inside the FLD attribute with the name 'phone' but Jasper keeps on returning a null, and I don't know why. I tried using the two methods you suggested but it still returns a null string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was missing out two forward slashes for retrieval of data. The following was to be used under the fieldDescription tag. //FLD[@NAME='Phone']. The two forward slashes before "FLD" were missing hence it wasn't displaying the value.